# Read multiple folders from sftp - Spring Integration & Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

we have spring integration with spring batch application where we process a file from a sftp server using a poller. have few questions on spring integration

```
 @Bean
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
    log.info("Polling for src msg : " + LocalDateTime.now());
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound"));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    return source;
}

@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    log.info("Creating sync");
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(ftpSrcPath);
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(srcFileName));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}
```

1. can we process multiple files from different directory
2. need to get the file directory from which folder the file was read from the sftp server

For the first question I read that mget function will be able to provide that feature but i m not getting the right example. pls help on this

Answer (score 1):

The `SftpInboundFileSynchronizer` does not support sub-dirs:

```
protected boolean isFile(LsEntry file) {
    return (file != null && file.getAttrs() != null && !file.getAttrs().isDir() && !file.getAttrs().isLink());
}
```

You can configure several channel adapters for the same output channel, but for different sub-dirs. The remote directory by itself in the `FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY` header. You also can use `#remoteDirectory` SpEL variable in the `localFilenameGeneratorExpression` option of the `SftpInboundFileSynchronizer`.

You also can use a  Polling Multiple Servers and Directories approach, but it is a bit complicated: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rotating-server-advice